# using select2 jquery with more than one form

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, jquery-select2

I have a formset in django, I've used `select2` for autocomplete, but it only works for the first form, won't affect the others. I need to provide id forms dynamically!

How can I replace `0` in `0model` with `form id`?

This is my template:

```js
//increase forms
<script>
    $('#add_model').click(function() {
    var form_idx = $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
    $('.model_formset').append($('#model_empty_formset').html().replace(/__prefix__/g, form_idx));
    $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(form_idx) + 1);
    $('.select2').select2()
   });
</script>
//my select2
```

```html
      <form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
          {{ model.management_form }}
 
        
        {% for form in model.forms %}
        <div class="col-12 row mx-auto p-2 model_formset">
            
            <div class="input-group inp mx-auto col-12 col-sm-10 p-1 col-md-5">
                 {{form.model_name | add_class:'select2 col-12 model text-center' | attr:'id:model'}}
              </div>
              
              <div class="input-group mx-auto inp col-12 col-sm-10 p-1 col-md-5">
                {{form.serial_number | add_class:'col-12 text-center'}}

            </div> 
        </div>
        
        {% endfor %}
        
        <div id="model_empty_formset" class="col-12 row mx-auto p-2" style="display: none; border-top:1px solid white;border-radius: 30px;">
            <hr class="col-10 bg-light">
            <div class="input-group inp mx-auto col-12 col-sm-10 p-1 col-md-5">
                {{model.empty_form.model_name | add_class:'col-12 text-center'}}
                {% if model.empty_form.model_name.errors %}
                <div class="error col-12 mx-auto">
                    {{model.model_name.errors }}
                </div>
                {% endif %}
              </div>
              
              <div class="input-group mx-auto inp col-12 col-sm-10 p-1 col-md-5">
                {{model.empty_form.serial_number | add_class:'col-12 text-center'}}
                {% if model.empty_form.serial_number.errors %}
                <div class="error col-12 mx-auto">
                    {{pcmodel.serial_number.errors }}
                </div>
                {% endif %}
            </div> 
        </div>        
          
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-7 col-md-3 mx-auto">
           <button class=" btn-block mt-1 shadow-lg border-right border-left">insert</button>
          </div>       
      </form>
```

Comment: add to all your selects some class e.q. "select2" and then activate it  $('.select2').select2()

Comment: @AndreyMaslov it wtill only work for the first one

Comment: what do you mean only first time? if you create form dynamically on your page, just after you add new form, call function where you have `$('.select2').select2();` You can place it in `$('#add_model').click`

Comment: for the first form , yes dynamic form , yes i did , but doesnt work , i used jquery.formset.js

Comment: can you provide resulted.html file?

Comment: updated with the picture

Comment: i meant resulted html code, so i can change it

Comment: i just moved this $('#0model').select2() to bottom of first script

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216875/discussion-between-andrey-maslov-and-art-cs).